How to access part of an HDF5 file from Node.js using HTTP range requests?
I'm trying to access an HDF5 file that is hosted at a URL, but I can't download the whole file since I'm working with files up to 50GB in size. Instead, I want to use HTTP range requests to slice through them. Is there a good tool for doing this from a Node.js server? I know that Python's h5py is capable of doing this well, so my backup plan is to set up a Python web server for doing this instead.
I've tried using h5wasm to do it, but h5wasm seem to require an actual file - which doesn't help since the whole point is to do this without downloading the whole file.
The goal is to be able to access data from the HDF5 file without it causing a noticeable lag in the web app that's consuming it.
